# Bootstrap positioning issue on small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap problem.

For normal screen (sm, md, lg), all is ok.

But for small screen (xs), I want the radio buttons part passes between the input and the button.

How to do that please ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
        <h4>TITLE</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-7">
        <input type="text" name="location">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button">SEND</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-offset-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="radio radio-inline checked">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" checked> RADIO 1
        </label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="radio"> RADIO 2
        </label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="radio"> RADIO 3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what _"I want the line 2 passes between the input and the button"_ means

Comment: Could you screenshot the intended and the actual behaviour as @j08691 says your question is not clear.

Comment: I want the radio buttons pass between the input and the button on a small device.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 2 line breaks, add them like so:

```
<br class="visible-xs"/>
<br class="visible-xs"/>
```

Otherwise, simply add the `.visible-xs` class to whatever you want visible at xtra small only.